# How does Perl handle password prompts?

Tags: perl, ssh, passwords

I'd like to pass a password through Perl. In my Perl script, it invokes SSH but gets stuck when the terminal is promoted for a password.

I've looked into using NET::SSH::Perl and other libraries but as of now they are not viable options. I just need to SSH into the machine, retrieve a file and leave.

Comment: We really need to see a sample of the problematic code to help. If you can add that, flag this question for moderator attention to be opened again.

Comment: @Tim Post, I don't think there is much confusion here. The OP wants to use SSH from his script to grab a file. Since he was just trying to use system to open the connection (as seen in comment to runrig) the process hangs as ssh waits for his password. I am assuming he doesn't want to work through the complexity of the large SSH modules to do his simple task, which is why I suggested an SFTP module instead. My answer addresses these issues and I believe solves the OPs problem. Hard to understand how this is not a real question.

Answer (score 2):

Besides [Net::SSH:Perl](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Net-SSH-Perl/), there's [Net::SSH2](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Net-SSH2/) and [Net::OpenSSH](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Net-OpenSSH/). What have you tried, and what problems have you had with them?

Comment: I ran a system (ssh user@host) and the terminal waits for a password input. How do I use Perl to type in the password so it can finish the login?

Answer (score 2):

[Expect](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Expect) is the standard way to automate applications that talk to `/dev/tty` as ssh.

Though, as runrig has already pointed out, there are several module available from CPAN specific to SSH. Is there any particular reason because you are unable to use them?

Answer (score 2):

You're telling me that [Net::SSH::Perl](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Net-SSH-Perl/) won't work? You can give `NET::SSH::Perl` your password when you do your connection.

They even give you an example on the page:

```
my $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new("host1");
$ssh->login("user1", "pass1");

$ssh->cmd("foo");
$ssh->cmd("bar");
```

Comment: I tried basically what you said, along with the CPAN documentation. Whenever I try to run the script, it runs into errors of of finding Math/Pari.pm.

Comment: `Math::Pari` is listed as a dependency of `Net::SSH::Perl` can you not install it or is it not functioning?

Comment: In researching my answer I found that `Net::SFTP::Foreign` doesn't have the dependencies of `Net::SSH::Perl` if that is becoming a show-stopper for you.

Comment: Did you use the "cpan" command? That's what you use to install modules in Perl. It handles the dependency issues. Click on the "Dependecies" limk in CPAN to see the [dependencies](http://deps.cpantesters.org/?module=Net%3A%3ASSH%3A%3APerl;perl=latest).

Comment: I ran "sudo perl -MCPAN -e 'install Net::SSH::Perl'" and it worked without any errors. But when I go to run the script, it says Can't locate Math/Pari.pm in @INC

Comment: Hmmm. I usually use just the `cpan` command line command, but this time I did the same Perl command you did. It detected that Math::Perl was required and not downloaded as well as dozens of other modules, then asked if I wanted them downloaded and installed, I said 'yes' to each requirement, and it installed them without a problem. You do have to say "Yes" to the prerequisites, and make sure they compile and install. Don't force it, or if a prerequisite fails, it'll still attempt to install your program.

Comment: Not all of us can work outside of standard perl. Just sayin.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Term::ReadPassword`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Term%3a%3aReadPassword) to get the user's password, then use that as an option to your SSH module of choice.

Since you only need to get a file and leave, you might try an SFTP module like `LWP`+[`LWP::Protocol::sftp`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?LWP%3a%3aProtocol%3a%3asftp) or [`Net::SFTP::Foriegn`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aSFTP%3a%3aForeign).

Here is an example using `Net::SFTP::Foreign` (which also has few dependencies):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Term::ReadPassword;
use Net::SFTP::Foreign;

my $pass = read_password("Enter Password: ");
my %opts = (
  host => "my.host.com",
  user => "me",
  password => $pass,
);

my $sftp = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new(%opts);

$sftp->get('/home/me/path/to/file', 'local_file');
```

Comment: I did not notice that the OP just wanted to retrieve a file. SFTP++. good call.